# System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'

Tags: c#

I am stuck here , the following method shows error

> 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'Cast' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)'
>   has some invalid arguments

How to resolve this I tried datatable.AsEnumerable but wont work. The bold lines in the code shows this error.
Help me please.

Here is the code

```
   public void DataExport(string SelectQuery)// server code
   {
       try
       {
           using (var dt = new DataTable())
           {
               using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectQuery, con))
               {
                   da.Fill(dt);
                   var rows =
                       **from dr in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()**
                       select String.Join(
                           ",",
                           **from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()**
                           let t1 = Convert.IsDBNull(dr[dc]) ? "" : dr[dc].ToString()
                           let t2 = t1.Contains(",") ? String.Format("\"{0}\"", t1) : t1
                           select t2);



                   using (var sw = new StreamWriter("somepath"))
                   {
                       // sw.WriteLine(header);
                       foreach (var row in rows)
                       {
                           sw.WriteLine(row);
                       }
                       sw.Close();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
   }
```

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: try: `from DataRow dr in dt.Rows`

Comment: To use `DataTable.AsEnumerable` you have to add a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` dll.

Comment: @PriyankaBarwad If you found a solution which helped you which isn't one of the answers, please add it yourself and mark it as the answer so the question isn't open any more.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to add `System.Linq` reference to your file.

```
using System.Linq;
```

[Enumerable.Cast Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)